# Revert computer name

Tags: 12.04

I changed computer name (host name) but forgot to make a backup, now sudo don't work. How can I fix this. I can't manually change /etc/hosts file because root controls that file, and I can't access it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try booting into recovery mode:

1. Hold shift during startup.
2. Select a "recovery mode" in the GRUB menu
3. Select "root".
4. Now you can edit `/etc/hosts` with `nano`

However, I'm not sure yet that the problem is in `/etc/hosts`. Can you add more details?

Comment: Thank you but I somehow managed to open /etc/hostname with sudo, then I set the exact name as it was in /etc/hosts. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

What about booting in recovery mode? Does that work? If not, try using a `chroot` as follows:

Boot your PC with a Live-CD and follow those steps:

Create a folder in `/media`. For example:

```
    sudo mkdir /media/chroot
```

then mount all needed drives and directories:

```
    sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/chroot
    sudo mount -o bind /dev /media/chroot/dev
    sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /media/chroot/pts
    sudo mount -o bind /sys /media/chroot/sys
    sudo mount -t proc /proc /media/chroot/proc
    sudo cp /proc/mounts /media/chroot/etc/mtab`
```

As for now, you can `chroot` in your system by using:

```
    sudo chroot /media/chroot /bin/bash
```

When "chrooted" in there, you can edit your `hostname`.